# Angularjs ng-fx animation applied to the wrong element

Tags: angularjs

I have created a simple app with simple animations where I can add and remove items to an array (used ng-fx for animations), but I have a problem.

When I try to add new elements, I get `ng-repeat duplicate error.` I fixed it by adding `track by $index`, but this time a new error occurs. If I try to remove an element from the list, wrong one is being animated.

Here's my plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/hKk9VGHIE1GT2i3P8TtT?p=preview

Here's my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="ng-fx.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="FirstController">
    <div ng-repeat="name in names track by $index" class="fx-fade-normal">
      {{name}}
      <input type="submit" value="Remove" ng-click="remove($index)">
    </div>


    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add" ng-click="add()">
  </div>
  <script>
    angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ng-fx']);

    angular.module('app').controller('FirstController', ["$scope", function($scope) {
      $scope.names = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"];

      $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.names.push($scope.name);
      };

      $scope.remove = function($index) {
        $scope.names.splice($index, 1);
      };


    }]);
  </script>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple change **ng-repeat="name in names track by $index"** to **ng-repeat="name in names track by $id(name)"**

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve the main problem, I still get dupes error when I try to add the same value to the array twice. Can you please share a working plnkr?

Comment: It's working look here. http://plnkr.co/edit/AIQVzC0biseLbRgAHJr2?p=preview. track by $id(name) works same like track by $index. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thanks, but this time animation issue still occurs. If you try to remove the element from the top of the page, it gets removed but not the way you'd expect to.

Comment: If this is the case then you have to create array of objects. This will solve your problem. Check updated Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/AIQVzC0biseLbRgAHJr2?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciated.